# iPhone warranty valid in another country?

Tags: iphone, warranty

I bought the iPhone 6 gold 64 gb three months ago from USA. But now I'm resident in India. Is there any way to transfer the warranty in India of my phone?

Comment: Not sure what the Title has to do with the Question. Best way to find out would be to ring Apple - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232

Answer (score 1):

Did you purchase AppleCare? It provides global coverage, so long as the necessary repair is available in the country you are now in. See [this page](https://www.apple.com/support/products/faqs.html).

If not, the standard [Apple Warranty](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/Images/worldwidewarranty.html) appears to state that if the device is portable, meaning it can operate independently without a power cord, you can obtain warranty service worldwide. (Scroll down on that page to the "Obtaining Warranty Service" section.)